# What is the meaning of python wrapper output?

Tags: python

I have written python wrapper for web interface [here](http://ws4jdemo.appspot.com/) to print the result of online computation on the terminal. Input to this computation are given through the code. 
The program I have done is:
    import re
    import mechanize
    import sys
    import os
    import urlparse

```
def calc_relatedness():
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.open("http://ws4jdemo.appspot.com/")
    br.select_form(nr = 0)
    br["w1"] = "tree#n#01"
    br["w2"] = "trunk#n#01"
    response = br.submit()
    print response
if __name__ == "__main__":
    calc_relatedness()
```

and output of above program is:

```
<response_seek_wrapper at 0x1ef2878 whose wrapped object = <closeable_response at  0x1efe170 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x1e8cb50>>>
```

Can anyone tell me what is the meaning of this output?

Expected output from web computation is:

```
wup( tree#n#1 , trunk#n#1 ) = 0.4762
jcn( tree#n#1 , trunk#n#1 ) = 0.0706
lch( tree#n#1 , trunk#n#1 ) = 1.2040
lin( tree#n#1 , trunk#n#1 ) = 0.1620
res( tree#n#1 , trunk#n#1 ) = 1.3696
path( tree#n#1 , trunk#n#1 ) = 0.0833
lesk( tree#n#1 , trunk#n#1 ) = 1066
hso( tree#n#1 , trunk#n#1 ) = 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output that you see is actually the string representation of the `response` object, defined in its class. You see, `response` actually contains more than the response body itself, it has other information like headers and url, too. Based on this code, if you want to get the response body, you should change the last line in `calc_relatedness()` to:

```
print response.read()
```

You can get some information about response by calling `response.info()` and `response.geturl()`.

Comment: thank you Sadjad...I am getting output in the form of html code (source code of the web page) I want to retrive only computational values. What should I do for it?

Comment: You need to use a library like BeautifulSoup to extract this data from HTML. Take a look into it and tell me if you needed help :) http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: Now again one more problem...computation results are in the form of images which are useless for me :-( Can I use java class inside python program?

Comment: You can use Jython for that purpose.